# How do you print a variable with text in python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.6

My code is:
snipername = str(input("What's the Sniper's name again?"))
print ("That's right,(snipername)! ")

(snipername) is my varible, but i can't figure out how to print it as well as the message.

Any help would be greatly apprectiated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use print("That's right, %s!" % (snipername))